# EC2 Load Balancer: What is the Difference Between LB and Instance Protocol

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, load-balancing

I am setting up a load balancer for my ec2 instances.  I'm a little confused about the difference between the options

```
Load Balancer Protocol
Load Balancer Port
Instance Protocol
Instance Port
```

In particular what is the difference between the "Load Balancer Protocol" and the "Instance Protocol"?  If I want to do SSL offloading on the LB but send through decrypted traffic to an instances web head listening on port 80, shoudl I use,

```
HTTPS 443 HTTP 80
```

or

```
HTTPS 443 HTTPS 443
```

What if I dont want to do SSL offloading at the LB?  What if I wanted to do it on an NGINX web head behind the LB?  In that case how would I configure this?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to offload SSL to the ELB, you would configure an HTTPS listener on the ELB and forward it to an HTTP listener (Often port 80).

If you want SSL to pass through to your instances, then you would just configure a TCP pass through listener.

Comment: Let me try that.  Im in the console now, so Ill try and see if I can do what you said.  Im going to start with 2, then try 1.  Do you have an opinion about SSL at the LB or at the instance?

Comment: SSL on the load balencer takes load off your instances. However some compliance scenarios require SSL all the way through.

Comment: "then you would just configure a TCP pass through listener"  How do I do that?

Comment: You would set the protocol to TCP, and listen on port 443, then send it to TCP/Port 443 on your instances.

Comment: It looks like as of today, ELB won't accept a configuration of TCP:443->TCP:443. I haven't been able to make an SSL pass-through connection work.